# AC Source RC Circuit Differential Equation

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, differential, parallel, remote-control

[image]

I have to find the differential equation to this circuit and I have been stuck for two days. I have tried: KCL in loop 1 and loop 2 but I don't know how to do the current through the inductor as Vi(t) since it is an AC input.

So far I have:
Vin(t)=1/c1 (integral)i1 dt + v2(t)

i1= C1dv2(t)/dt -v2(t)/R1
i2=?

Sorry about the format! First time poster on here.

Comment: KCL applies to nodes, not loops. KVL is for loops. Also, are you looking to get the complete solution that works for t >= 0? Or just write down the right KCL or KVL equations? (But not solve them.)

Comment: *but I don't know how to do the current through the inductor *. There is no inductor. Did you mean KVL?

Comment: spying, You will likely need to say something (if nothing else, to show you are still here and interested.) Can you help us to help you?